# ¿Programa que calcula la media y la varianca da resultado diferentes con la calculadora?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Tengo dos arrays de NumPy llamados `follow_dismiss_i` y `follow_dismiss_display_i` que contienen una primera columna que contiene contadores y una segunda columna que son índices.

He creado un programa que me ayude calcular :

- El resultado de `SUM_follow_dismiss` y `SUM_follow_dismiss_display` que son las sumas de las segundas columnas de `follow_dismiss_i` y `follow_dismiss_display_i` respectivamente.
- Obtengo un array llamado `m_i` que es el resultado de dividir la primera columna de `follow_dismiss_i` entre su homóloga de `follow_dismiss_display_i` usando para ello los índices (segunda columna). Si un índice existe en `follow_dismiss_i` pero no en `follow_dismiss_display_i`, en `m_i` ese índice va asociado a un valor de 0.0.
- La varianza del array `m_i`.

También calculo la media, `m` pero resulta que obtengo  0.517134831461, como se puede ver en la salida de mi código, mientras que sobre la calculadora tengo `0.63567076`.

Intento entender por qué hay estas diferencias y si  existe un método mucho más sencillo para hacerlo.

Este es mi código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Small script for some stats
#

import traceback
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# pueden necesitar los arrays siguients que estan en el output :

print "follow_dismiss_i"
print follow_dismiss_i
print "SUM_follow_dismiss"
print SUM_follow_dismiss
print "follow_dismiss_display_i"
print follow_dismiss_display_i
print "SUM_follow_dismiss_display"
print SUM_follow_dismiss_display

m = float(SUM_follow_dismiss)/ SUM_follow_dismiss_display
print ("\nmean m")
print m

m_i=[]

print "\nvariance"
for j in range(len(follow_dismiss_display_i)):
    new = []
    found = 0
    for i in range(len(follow_dismiss_i)):
        if follow_dismiss_display_i[j,1]==follow_dismiss_i[i,1]:
            new.append(follow_dismiss_display_i[j,1])
            new.append(float(follow_dismiss_i[i,0])/follow_dismiss_display_i[j,0])
            m_i.append(new)
            found=1         
            break
    if found == 0:
        new.append(follow_dismiss_display_i[j,1])
        new.append(0.0)
        m_i.append(new)
test = np.array(m_i)
print test[:,1]
variance_eclipse = np.var(test[:,1])

print variance_eclipse
```

Aqui esta el output por si lo necesitan para reproducirel programa con mis mismos datos:

```
follow_dismiss_i
[[505  13]
 [ 14  54]
 [ 70  68]
 [ 21 150]
 [ 36 152]
 [ 62 156]
 [ 59 158]
 [120 160]
 [ 53 161]
 [150 162]
 [  3 169]
 [  1 171]
 [ 60 172]
 [  1 177]
 [126 179]
 [ 41 185]
 [239 189]
 [163 190]
 [ 26 216]
 [ 42 223]
 [  1 272]
 [  2 286]
 [  5 289]
 [  1 292]
 [  2 294]
 [  6 296]
 [ 25 306]
 [  7 312]]
SUM_follow_dismiss
1841
follow_dismiss_display_i
[[986  13]
 [ 20  54]
 [484  68]
 [ 57 150]
 [ 44 152]
 [ 95 156]
 [ 89 158]
 [144 160]
 [ 58 161]
 [383 162]
 [  3 169]
 [  2 171]
 [125 172]
 [  1 177]
 [147 179]
 [ 61 185]
 [325 189]
 [334 190]
 [ 46 216]
 [ 71 223]
 [  1 272]
 [  2 276]
 [  9 286]
 [  5 289]
 [  1 292]
 [  2 294]
 [ 10 296]
 [ 27 306]
 [ 16 312]
 [ 12 315]]
SUM_follow_dismiss_display
3560

mean
0.517134831461

variance
[ 0.51217039  0.7         0.1446281   0.36842105  0.81818182  0.65263158
  0.66292135  0.83333333  0.9137931   0.39164491  1.          0.5         0.48
  1.          0.85714286  0.67213115  0.73538462  0.48802395  0.56521739
  0.5915493   1.          0.          0.22222222  1.          1.          1.
  0.6         0.92592593  0.4375      0.        ]
0.0858073520518
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El resultado de la media no debe variar tanto entre lo que calcula Python y una calculadora, no más allá de la precisión con la que trabaje esa calculadora.

La `m` que calculas es el resultado de sumar todos los 'counts' (columna 0) de `follow_dismiss` por un lado y de `follow_dismiss_display` por otro y dividir ambos 1841 / 3560 = 0.517134831461. Ese es el resultado que obtenemos tanto en Python como en un calculadora.

No termino de entender que significado tiene esa 'media' tal y como la obtienes, Por buscar una explicación, creo que debería ser la media de `test[:, 1]` que si da 0.635 y no lo que estas calculando, aunque esto es solo una suposición.

Aparte de lo anterior, para este tipo de cálculos deberias usar Pandas (ya que lo tienes importado y todo). Te simplifica mucho las cosas. Por ejemplo, para hacer lo que haces en tus ciclos `for` anidados basta con usar [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Para ello especifivamos que se aplique sobre las columnas de los índices (parámetro `on`) y que tenga en cuenta solo los índices de `follow_dismiss_display_i` (parámetro `how = 'left'` indicando que tenga en cuenta el primer array). Los índices que no tengan correspondencia en `follow_dismiss_i` quedaran con valor NaN que podemos pasar a 0.0 sin problemas cuando hagamos la división:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


a = pd.DataFrame(follow_dismiss_display_i, columns = ('counts', 'indx'))
b = pd.DataFrame(follow_dismiss_i, columns = ('counts', 'indx'))

SUM_follow_dismiss_display = a['counts'].sum()
SUM_follow_dismiss = b['counts'].sum()

c = pd.merge(a, b, how = 'left', on= 'indx')
c['div'] = c['counts_y'].div(c['counts_x'], fill_value=0.0)
test = c[['indx', 'div']].values
m = np.mean(test[:,1])
variance_eclipse = np.var(test[:,1])

print 'SUM_follow_dismiss_display: ', SUM_follow_dismiss_display
print 'SUM_follow_dismiss: ', SUM_follow_dismiss
print 'test[:,1]: \n', test[:,1]
print 'mean: ', m
print 'variance: ', variance_eclipse
```

Usando los datos de entrada que dás:

```
follow_dismiss_i= np.array([[505,  13],
                            [ 14,  54],
                            [ 70,  68],
                            [ 21, 150],
                            [ 36, 152],
                            [ 62, 156],
                            [ 59, 158],
                            [120, 160],
                            [ 53, 161],
                            [150, 162],
                            [  3, 169],
                            [  1, 171],
                            [ 60, 172],
                            [  1, 177],
                            [126, 179],
                            [ 41, 185],
                            [239, 189],
                            [163, 190],
                            [ 26, 216],
                            [ 42, 223],
                            [  1, 272],
                            [  2, 286],
                            [  5, 289],
                            [  1, 292],
                            [  2, 294],
                            [  6, 296],
                            [ 25, 306],
                            [  7, 312]])


follow_dismiss_display_i = np.array([ [986, 13],
                                      [ 20, 54],
                                      [484, 68],
                                      [ 57, 150],
                                      [ 44, 152],
                                      [ 95, 156],
                                      [ 89, 158],
                                      [144, 160],
                                      [ 58, 161],
                                      [383, 162],
                                      [  3, 169],
                                      [  2, 171],
                                      [125, 172],
                                      [  1, 177],
                                      [147, 179],
                                      [ 61, 185],
                                      [325, 189],
                                      [334, 190],
                                      [ 46, 216],
                                      [ 71, 223],
                                      [  1, 272],
                                      [  2, 276],
                                      [  9, 286],
                                      [  5, 289],
                                      [  1, 292],
                                      [  2, 294],
                                      [ 10, 296],
                                      [ 27, 306],
                                      [ 16, 312],
                                      [ 12, 315]])
```

Obtenemos:

> ```
> SUM_follow_dismiss_display:  3560
> SUM_follow_dismiss:  1841
> test[:,1]: 
> [ 0.51217039  0.7         0.1446281   0.36842105  0.81818182  0.65263158
>   0.66292135  0.83333333  0.9137931   0.39164491  1.          0.5         0.48
>   1.          0.85714286  0.67213115  0.73538462  0.48802395  0.56521739
>   0.5915493   1.          0.          0.22222222  1.          1.          1.
>   0.6         0.92592593  0.4375      0.        ]
> mean:  0.635760767848
> variance:  0.0858073520518
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy claro... como siempre...